# Sequelize - TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

**EDIT: There was a line present in my code that was left out of my example, it has been added and labeled with a comment.**

I'm setting up a server for a new project and attempting to use Sequelize for the first time since v5. Upon running my server, this error is thrown.

```
/Users/me/dev/projects/my-project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:730
    options = Utils.merge(_.cloneDeep(globalOptions.define), options);
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
    at Function.init (/Users/me/dev/projects/my-project/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:730:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/dev/projects/my-project/src/server/db/models/user.js:16:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    ...
```

The error occurs during the invocation of my model definition initialization:

```
const sequelize = require("../_db");

...

console.log('this runs');

class User extends Sequelize.Model {} // edit: this line was here
User.init(
  {
    avatar: {
      default: {
        type: Sequelize.URL,
        value: defaultAvatar
      },
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    id: {
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: false,
      get() {
        return () => this.getDataValue("password");
      },
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    salt: {
      get() {
        return () => this.getDataValue("salt");
      },
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: "user" }
);

console.log('this doesn't);
```

This is pretty cryptic to me, I'm not quite sure what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the class definition for user. 
I can't see it in the code you've provided. 
This would explain why the error says it is from "undefined"

i.e.

```
const Model = Sequelize.Model;    
class User extends Model {}
```

You could do:

```
class User extends Sequelize.Model {}
```

See here:
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

Additionally, it looks like you are using Sequelize's default model loader, you will need to have that model defined inside a

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("User", {

  });

  return User
};
```

Comment: this is my bad, I somehow left out that line of code in my question, but I do have `class User extends Sequelize.Model {}` present. However the method of exporting my model seemed to do the trick.